# Can't go up in listView because SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Can anyone help me with this?

I have one listView in one RelativeLayout which is child of SwipeRefreshLayout. This is everything a view of one fragment.

Here is a pic of layout and this screenshot is taken when i was at the bottom of ListView, so when i try to go up i'm also loading the SwipeRefresh and it's really hard to go at the top of the ListView.

I have tried something like including ScrollView before RelativeLayout and after SwipeRefreshLayout and successed. Scrolling was working good, but it was only working if i extend listView to 2400 dp and i'm not getting good view. I have some emptiness at the bottom of the ListView and that's not i want.

So if anyone have any suggestion what could i do, let me know.

Here is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the fragment  to be displayed for a section associated with a tab -->
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/lista_preporuka_selector" >        
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>   

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the listview directly inside the swipe tor refresh and remove the realtive layout
This works great to me

Answer (score 4):

I solved this programatically using the solution explained [here](http://nlopez.io/swiperefreshlayout-with-listview-done-right/).

Basically you override the scroll listener for the listview and only enable the swipe to refresh if the scroll is at the top of the list:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {  
  @Override
  public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    int topRowVerticalPosition = (listView== null || listView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : listView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
    swipeContainer.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Swipe refresh wasn't designed with anything other than list inside of it. 
If you have to use it that way disable refreshing until your list reaches top but i'm not certain if that will work.

Comment: I can confirm that your suggestion works. I took the same approach whenever I was forced to have a `ListView` that was not a direct child of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`